# How to wait for my services function to finish in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I made a service with a function.

```
app.service('getService', ['$http', function($http){    
    this.getProducts = function(log = true){
         $http({
             url: "/admin/products"
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
             log == true ? console.log(response) : false;
             return response.data;
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
             log == true ? console.log(response) : false;
         });
    }
}]);
```

After that, I call it and waiting for function to finish, but this not working.

```
app.controller('categoryCtrl', ['$scope','staticsService', function ($scope, getService) {
    turnonloader();
    $scope.model = getService.getProducts().then(function(){
        turnoffloader();
        console.log("Finished!");
    });
}]);
```

Which is the best solution?

Comment: you need to return something from `getProducts`, so `return $http(...);`

Comment: The controller erroneously injects `'staticService'` when the service is named `'getService'`.

Comment: I'm sorry for bad editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service should `return` the promise:

```
app.service('getService', ['$http', function($http){    
    this.getProducts = function(log = true){
         ̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶(̶{̶
         return $http({
             url: "/admin/products"
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
             log == true ? console.log(response) : false;
             return response.data;
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
             log == true ? console.log(response) : false;
             //IMPORTANT
             throw response;
         });
    }
}]);
```

Also it is important that the error handler re-throw the error response. Otherwise the promise will be **converted** from a rejection to a successful promise that returns `undefined`.